# How to work with fragments with Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-fragmentactivity, android-bluetooth

I have an activity that holds a navigation menu to 3 fragments:

1) Home (with channel change and volume change buttons) 
2) Bluetooth connection (which connects with an external bluetooth device)
3) Settings (where the seekbar to change the squelch of the bluetooth device)

When the app opens up, all the navigation button works in terms of opening the individual fragments.

After I go to the Bluetooth connection fragment, which takes me to the phone's setting to set up the bluetooth connection to the external bluetooth device, the app will take you to the Home fragment.

All the buttons (channel and volume change buttons) in the Home fragment works in terms of interacting with the external device (the lights blink to show interaction). However, after interacting with the buttons, the navigational buttons to the other fragments (Setting fragment and Bluetooth fragment) do not work (the fragments do not appear/pull up).

Also, the other bug is that if I opened the app and go to the Settings fragment, none of the buttons (channel and volume change buttons, the lights in the external bluetooth device do not work) in the Home fragment do not work.

***UPDATE***

Ok, so an interesting observation I found was that the squelch button in the 3) Settings fragment also works if I never went to the 1) Home fragment initially and went straight to the Settings fragment.

I was experimenting with a prototype I built using Activity instead of Fragment and it showed similar behaviour in terms of the bluetooth connection breaking up if I switched between activities without closing the connection properly.

This leads me to believe that when I switch between fragments, the connection doesn't close properly, hence rendering the buttons not to work (the external device doesn't blink).

Question - how do I close the connection when making the view invisible?

Thanks!

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak directly to all of the issues you described, but I will say that in the past, I too have encountered behavioural issues using fragments when a workflow I didn't account for occurs. Specifically, you want to make sure that your fragment manager, which you are using to handle your fragment transitions, is both knowledge about where in your fragment stack you are (and should be), and what items should be in your backstack.

For example, an issue I ran into was a device rotation that I was not handling correctly, causing my activity/fragment to be recreated, which in turn messed up my fragment stack. This lead to weirdness when using the back button to navigate through the app, such as UI elements not responding properly, or appearing when they shouldn't have.

I don't know how the movement between your fragments and the phones settings may be negatively affecting you, but in general, it's important that you track your savedInstanceStates, and onResult if relevant, when you leave your app or cause an activity restart.

Answer (score 0):

I got my app to work the way I wanted to.

What I was doing was to open a new Bluetooth connection everytime a new fragment opens so I am suspecting that each connection was conflicting with one another if I didn't close it properly on view change.

What I did to fix it was to open up a single, global Bluetooth connection when the Activity opens and let the individual fragments access that Bluetooth connection variable.

Thanks.

Comment: hi, how do you define the service in the activity? I got main activity that handles change in fragments using a view pager, with 3 tabs. In the first fragment the BT is discovered, conected, receive and send message. Can´t make it to bind the service in the second and third tabs.